# How to select objects from JSON file and push into new file when they fail API validation

Tags: ruby, json, httparty

I am working with an API which accepts some JSON objects (sent as post request) and fails others based on certain criteria.

I am trying to compile a "log" of the objects which have failed and ones which have been validated successfully so I don't have to manually copy and paste them each time. (There are hundreds of objects).

Basically if the API returns "false", I want to push that object into a file, and if it returns true, all those objects go into another file.

I have tried to read a bunch of documentation / blogs on "select, detect, reject" etc enumerators but my problem is very different from the examples given.

I have written some pseudo code in my ruby file below and I think I'm going along the right lines, but need a bit of guidance to complete the task:

```
restaurants = JSON.parse File.read('pretty-minified.json')

restaurants.each do |restaurant|
create_response = HTTParty.post("https://api.hailoapp.com/business/create",
{
  :body => restaurant.to_json,
  :headers => { "Content-Type" => "text", "Accept" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Authorization" => "token #{api_token}" }
  })
  data = create_response.to_hash
  alert = data["valid"]
  if alert == false
    # select restaurant json objects which return false and push into new file
    # false_rest = restaurants.detect { |r| r == false }
    File.open('false_objects.json', 'w') do |file|
      file << JSON.pretty_generate(false_rest)
    else
    # select restaurant json objects which return true and push into another file
    File.open('true_objects.json', 'w') do |file|
      file << JSON.pretty_generate()
  end 

end
```

An example of the output (JSON) from the API is as follows:

```
{"id":"102427","valid":true}
{"valid":false}
```

The JSON file is basically an huge array of hashes (or objects), here is a short excerpt:

```
[
  {
    "id": "223078",
    "name": "3 South Place",
    "phone": "+442032151270",
    "email": "3sp@southplacehotel.com",
    "website": "",
    "location": {
      "latitude": 51.5190536,
      "longitude": -0.0871038,
      "address": {
        "line1": "3 South Place",
        "line2": "",
        "line3": "",
        "postcode": "EC2M 2AF",
        "city": "London",
        "country": "UK"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "210071",
    "name": "5th View Bar & Food",
    "phone": "+442077347869",
    "email": "waterstones.piccadilly@elior.com",
    "website": "http://www.5thview.com",
    "location": {
      "latitude": 51.5089594,
      "longitude": -0.1359897,
      "address": {
        "line1": "Waterstone's Piccadilly",
        "line2": "203-205 Piccadilly",
        "line3": "",
        "postcode": "W1J 9HA",
        "city": "London",
        "country": "UK"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "239971",
    "name": "65 & King",
    "phone": "+442072292233",
    "email": "hello@65king.com",
    "website": "http://www.65king.com/",
    "location": {
      "latitude": 51.5152533,
      "longitude": -0.1916538,
      "address": {
        "line1": "65 Westbourne Grove",
        "line2": "",
        "line3": "",
        "postcode": "W2 4UJ",
        "city": "London",
        "country": "UK"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to filter by emails, ending with `elior.com` (this condition might be easily changed):

NB! The data above looks like a javascript var, it’s not a valid ruby object. I assume you just got it from somewhere as a string. That’s why `json`:

```
require 'json'
array = JSON.parse(restaurants) # data is a string: '[{....... as you received it
result = array.group_by do |e|
  # more sophisticated condition goes here 
  e['email'] =~ /elior\.com$/ ? true : false
end
File.open('false_objects.json', 'w') do |file|
  file << JSON.pretty_generate(result[false])
end
File.open('true_objects.json', 'w') do |file|
  file << JSON.pretty_generate(result[true])
end
```

There is a hash in `result`, containing two elements:

```
#⇒ { 
#     true: [..valids here ..],
#     false: [..invalids here..]
# }
```

Comment: Yes, I know the data is not ruby, but I'm parsing the JSON, and treating the list of JSON objects as hashes within an array.

Comment: Then `JSON.parse` will make an array out of it and the following [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) will split this array into two parts as you requested.

Comment: Thanks @mudasobwa, is that square bracket syntax correct? Can I write to a file within that and it will work?

Comment: Where can I find documentation on this syntax / technique?

Comment: I am not sure I understood the question about square brackets. For documentation on `group_by` please follow the link in my previous comment. `group_by` will give you a hash consisting of two elements: valids under `true` key and invalids under `false` then you might ... Well, please see an update.

Comment: excellent, tried this edited version and it worked wonderfully! Thanks @mudasobwa you just need to get rid of the else, and add ends to the two file do blocks

Comment: Oh, yes, indeed, that was copy-pasted from your question.